# Swift date format returning wrong date

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

I need to convert my **date** to **string** and then **string** to **date**. date is "**2020-10-17 1:22:01 PM +0000**"

**Here is my date to string conversion code:**

```
                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX"
                     let string = formatter.string(from: "2020-10-17 1:22:01 PM +0000")
                    let createdAT = string
```

its returning **"2020-10-17 18:51:30+05:30"**

**Here is my string to date conversion code:**

```
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ssZ"
     let date = dateFormatter.date(from:date)!
```

its returning **"2020-10-17 1:21:30 PM +0000 - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 624633690.0"**

its returning the wrong date after i convert string to date. i need **"2020-10-17 18:51:30+05:30"** this time to be return when i convert string to date.....

Comment: *2020-10-17 1:21:30 PM +0000* and *2020-10-17 18:51:30+05:30* are the same time.

Comment: A Date object has no format, it holds a representation of time and nothing else so you code is pointless. Use the original Date object as it is and then performa a format to string when you need to display/print it.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes. but i need 020-10-17 1:21:30 PM +0000 to 020-10-17 1:21:30 PM +0000 when i convert string to date.. what kind change i that i need to add this code

Comment: You need to use a `DateFormatter` to convert it to a string and set an appropriate timezone on the date formatter

Comment: @JoakimDanielson since i new to swift can you please guide me. with sample of code

Comment: @Paulw11  thats what im trying in the second part of my code. is there any wrong in that.

Comment: You need to use [`string(from:Date)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415810-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your question is muddled up. You try to convert a string into a string in the first example and something unspecified into a `Date` in the second example.

Here's how to convert a `Date` into a `String`:

```
import Foundation

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX"
let string: String = formatter.string(from: Date())

print(string) // prints for example 2020-10-18T10:54:07+01:00
```

Here's how to convert a string into a date

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ssZ"
let date: Date = formatter.date(from: "2020-10-18 10:59:56+0100")! // In real life, handle the optional properly
print(date)  // prints 2020-10-18 09:59:56 +0000
```

When you print a Date directly, it automatically uses UTC as the time zone. This is why it changed it in the code above.

In the examples, I explicitly specified the type of `string` and `date` to show what type they are. Type inference means you can omit these in normal code.

As a general rule when handling dates:

- always use `Date` in your code. `Date` is a type that stores the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970 UTC.
- Only convert dates to strings when displaying them to the user or communicating with an external system.
- When calculating periods etc, always use a [Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar) to get things like date components and intervals in units other than seconds. You might think to get "the same time tomorrow" you could just add 24 * 60 * 60 to a `Date` but in many countries, like mine, that will work on only 363 days in the year. `Calendar` will correctly handle things like daylight saving and leap years.